# vue.js - not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am loading a template that references a client side js file with my code like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/app.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="map">
    <script src="../js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <div id="offer-details">
    <form id="offer-form" v-on:submit="makeOffer(tags, description, code)">  
      <input id="description"/>
      <input id="tags"/>
      <input id="code"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

My browser shows that the following (details.js) loads successfully.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#details",
    data: {
    offer: {
            publickey: '',
            privatekey: '',          
            name: '',
            service: '',
            value: '',
            currency: '',
            tags: '',
            description: '',
            code: ''
    },             
    methods: {
        makeOffer: function makeOffer(){console.log(vm.publickey)}

    }
    }   
})
```

However, when I submit the form I get the following error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "makeOffer" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in root instance)vue.js:2574:7

[Vue warn]: Handler for event "submit" is undefined.
```

It looks to me like I'm defining makeOffer in the method key as I should.  Is this not the same as defining it on the instance?  Why isn't it seeing makeOffer?

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: I got this error because I did not have closing `</script>` tag in my component file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to make sure `makeOffer` is inside the methods option (which itself is outside the data option). Right now you have the methods option inside the data option. Also, you can't log the `publickey` using `vm.publickey`; instead, you should use `this.offer.publickey`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, that seems to be the problem because there's no more error.  However, my makeOffer function still doesn't seem to be working because nothing is logged in the console.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm not sure I understood what you wanted to do, but I binded things together…

Here is a working snippet:

```js
  var vm = new Vue({
el: "#details",
data: {
  offer: {
      publickey: '',
      privatekey: '',          
      name: '',
      service: '',
      value: '',
      currency: '',
      tags: '',
      description: '',
      code: ''
    }
},             
methods: {
  makeOffer() {
    console.log(this.offer)
  }
}
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="map">  
<div id="details">
  <form id="offer-form" v-on:submit="makeOffer">  
    <input v-model="offer.description" />
    <input v-model="offer.tags" />
    <input v-model="offer.code"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to call the makeOffer method when the form submits.  This still doesn't let me do that because of the error messages I mentioned.

Comment: the code snippet above calls the makeoffer functionon submit and has no errors

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that you had methods defined outside of data, that was the problem.

Comment: I'm using your pasted code and there are no errors any more, but the console.log command doesn't log anything to the console - even though it does on the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons could be, the type or syntax error in the `js` file where the `Vue` methods are declared. So, double check that too, like:

```
var app= new Vue({
  ....
  methods: {
    platform_click: function (event) {
      Alert("hi"):     // typo error or ; missing
    }
  }
  ...
});
```